# How to avoid sending to display the view after the model update fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started programming with Ruby on Rails and I found a problem. When I edit a model and this fails in validation from controller, the controller return the #show model url. After that when I cancel the #update and go to #view the model, for a moment the browser shows me the error page that the #update process return previously. I dont like this behavior. I think that problem is Turbolink. So I dont know if I can change the url for #update in controller. Any ideas why happens this? Thanks advanced.

[The next image shows this behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WxlX.gif)

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1
  # PATCH/PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

## show page:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Categoría #<%= @category.id %></h2>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Detalles de la categoría
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Nombre</dt>
            <dd><%= @category.name %></dd>
        </dl>
        <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_category_path(@category), class: 'btn btn-link' %> |
        <%= link_to 'Volver', categories_path, class: 'btn btn-link' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using flash messages? can you provide the code for your controller and view?

Comment: I'm using scaffold for generate all. This is the code of categories controller and the view show.
http://collabedit.com/qh2a8

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your are using Rails Admin gem. Seem likes this is pjax problem. So you can disable pjax, more details [here](http://def%20attachment_url(object,%20name,%20*args,%20host:%20nil,%20prefix:%20nil,%20filename:%20nil,%20format:%20nil)%20%20%20attacher%20=%20object.send(:#%7Bname%7D_attacher%22)%20%20%20file%20=%20attacher.get%20%20%20return%20unless%20file%20%20%20%20filename%20%7C%7C=%20attacher.basename%20%7C%7C%20name.to_s%20%20%20format%20%7C%7C=%20attacher.extension%20%20%20%20file_url(file,%20*args,%20host:%20host,%20prefix:%20prefix,%20filename:%20filename,%20format:%20format)%20end)

Comment: No, I'm not using Rails Admin gem. I'm using scaffold command for generate all.